# How to partially fill an svg path using percentage value?

Tags: html, svg, sunburst-diagram

I have used the code from this [link](https://bl.ocks.org/snowshine09/da30c4da5400ee0b67df04e2961e9aca) to implement a sunburst design.
Below is the svg path element which is an arc.

```
<g class="node" style="opacity: 1;"><path id="Arc_12" d="M-216.50635094610962,125.00000000000009A250,250,0,0,1,-4.5924254968025744e-14,-250L-3.6739403974420595e-14,-200A200,200,0,0,0,-173.2050807568877,100.00000000000007Z" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); fill: rgb(20, 76, 76);"></path><text style="font-size: 12px; fill: white; text-transform: full-width;" dx="0" dy="27"><textPath startOffset="25%" style="dominant-baseline: middle; text-anchor: middle;" xlink:href="#Arc_12">COMPLETED 75%</textPath></text></g>
```

The above element is currently filled with rgb(20, 76, 76) which occupies 100% of the path. I need it to fill only 75% of the path to indicate the progress. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 75% of the path element with any color.

Comment: So random dots that cover 75% of the path's area? Fill the bottom, the top, the left, the right? Something else?

Comment: Its like a progress bar. I just want to indicate that it is 75 % complete.

Comment: if u see this https://bl.ocks.org/snowshine09/da30c4da5400ee0b67df04e2961e9aca , section "Others" is 100% filled with orange. How can I make it 75%?

Comment: Set the path's fill to a linearGradient and set the stops on that gradient so that there's 75% visible.

Comment: @Robert I tried filling the path with gradient but ended up with 100% fill.

Comment: My bad..I got it. Thanks Robert.

Comment: @Robert Can u help me with this?

Comment: You shouldn't radically change your question. Best to ask another question since you seem to have moved on from this question.